# Pass string parameter to remote process in kdb

Tags: kdb

I am trying to pass a variable that is string to the ipc query. This does not work for me.

Example:

```
[`EDD.RDB; "?[`tab;enlist(like;`OrderId;",("string Number),");();(?:;`Actions)]"]
```

I am trying to query this RDB where OrderId like Number(string)
Number is a parameter but when I passed as string to the remote process, Number is not string any more. I tried to put string in front but still get the same result.

What I want to pass to remote process is this:

```
Number:"abc"
"?[`tab;enlist(like;`OrderId;"abc");();(?:;`Actions)]"
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT as you have updated your question.

It's hard to give a solid answer here as your example is lacking information.

What you have posted is not a valid IPC call in KDB+. I suspect what you may be trying to run is something like:

```
h(`EDD.RDB; "?[`tab;enlist(like;`OrderId;",("string Number),");();(?:;`Actions)]"])
```

Assuming Number is an int (e.g. `Number:123`) then in that case you could rewrite it as:

```
h(`EDD.RDB;"select distinct Actions from t where orderID like \"",string[Number],"\"")
```

Which is easier to read and work with. Assuming `Number` is defined on the client side then the above should return an answer.

If you do want to use functional form then you could try something like:

```
"?[`tab;enlist (like;`orderID;string[",string[Number],"]);1b;(enlist`Actions)!enlist`Actions]"
```

As your query string.

If Number is already a string on your process, e.g `Number:"123"` then you should be able to either:

```
h(`EDD.RDB;"select distinct Actions from t where orderID like \"",Number,"\"")
OR
h(`EDD.RDB;"?[`tab;enlist (like;`orderID;string[",Number,"]);1b;(enlist`Actions)!enlist`Actions]")
```

Answer (score 3):

Does the IPC query have to be string? Passing parameters would be cleaner using `(func;params)` syntax for IPC.

```
handleToRdb ({[number] ?[`tab;enlist(like;`OrderId;number);();(?:;`Actions)]};"abc")
```